# Chrome: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier, Firefox:SyntaxError: missing ] after element list

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I am getting the following JavaScript error:

In Chrome:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

and in Firefox:

```
SyntaxError: missing ] after element list
```

I am making an **ajax query** to get **JSON** data from **PHP** using the following script.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        setInterval($.ajax({                                      
            url: 'process.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data){
        for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                $("h1").html(data[0]+" "+data[1]);
        }
        }
    }), 5000);
    return false;
}); 
</script>
```

The **JSON** I am getting is in the format

```
["Avg\u00e5ngar:","Resecentrum (V\u00e4xj\u00f6) kl. 13:33","Linje","Destination","N\u00e4sta tur (min)","\u00a0","D\u00e4refter","\u00a0","1","Hovshaga C","57","--","1","Kurortsv\u00e4gen via Hovshaga C","7","18","1","Teleborg","15","54","2","Resecentrum via Araby","12","--","3","Grand Samarkand","17","47","4","H\u00f6gstorp","ca 12","ca 42","4","\u00d6jaby via \u00d6 R\u00e4ppe","18","--","5","Sandsbro","7","37","5","Teleborg","10","40","6","Resecentrum via Norr","27","--","7","Evedal","45","--","7","Universitetet","6","21","7","\u00d6stra Lugnet","11","--","21","Centrum-\u00d6ster-Norr-Centrum","27","--","22","Centrum-Hov-Centrum","47","--","23","Centrum-S\u00f6der-Centrum","14","--","50","Smaland Airport","37","--","114","Gransholm","ca 7","--","123","\u00c4lmhult","ca 32","--","144","Ljungby","ca 37","--","145","Halmstad","27","--","215","Tingsryd","ca 27","--","217","Billa","52","--","218","Kosta","2","ca 52","240","Ronneby","ca 42","--","241","J\u00e4t","ca 57","--","310","\u00c5seda","ca 27","ca 57","331","Fr\u00f6seke","ca 37","--","350","Rottne Bra\u00e5s","ca 37","--"]
```

which seems to be valid when tested in [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/). What might be the reason behind it?

Comment: Inside `success` method put an `console.log(data)` and post what you're getting in console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated Answer for your question in the comments**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    callAjax();
    setInterval(function(){
        callAjax();
    }, 5000);

    function callAjax(){
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'process.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $("h1").html(data[0]+" "+data[1]);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    return false;
});
```

**Old Answer:**

Please look for your syntax errors yourself next time since SO is not here for this kind of problems.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    setInterval(function(){
        $.ajax({                                      
            url: 'process.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
                    $("h1").html(data[0]+" "+data[1]);
                }
            }
        });
    }, 5000);
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Sorry my bad, I missed that. And while we are at it, the setInterval executes every 5 secs which is fine but I want the html rendered right away for the first time. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Put the contents of your setInterval into a different function e.g. executeAjax(). Before your setInterval you call this function. Within your setInterval you also call this function. I'll make a quick edit